# Combine multiple databases in SQL Server based on table name and column name as a new table or view

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, database-schema

I have 100+ databases on a server, each database has a table named `song` and in that table has a column named `title`.

I need to create a dynamic SQL query to do this if possible to create a table or a new view.

Here is the script I created but not sure how to join as a union across the 100+ databases

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 

'USE [?];
PRINT ''DBName='' + DB_Name()

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = ''Song'')

BEGIN

SELECT [DBName] = DB_Name(), title
FROM dbo.Song

END
'
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting a 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: thank you but where does it create the view when I run it? Can I just tell it to give me the query as a result?

Comment: instead of exec(@sql) .. use print @sql or select @sql..and if the @sql is too long (print returns only a limited number of characters) then `select @sql for xml path('')` .. and if you want a view then uncomment `/*
select @sql = 'create view dbo.myview as
' + @sql;
*/` ..the exec(@sql) will create a view named dbo.myview

Comment: how can I create an exception for a database to be excluded from server. I got this 'Database 'MusicUsers' cannot be opened because it is offline.'

Comment: thank you but it is not populating when I change to select @sql. How do I populate results from all 'dbo.Song' and field = title under the same server and the results include individual fields title, db.name separately in own fields?